# Change units of matplotlib subplot (RA hh:mm to degrees)

Tags: matplotlib, coordinates, subplot, astropy, units-of-measurement

I am trying to plot an image with axes in RA and DEC. I cannot figure out how to change units from h:m:s to deg for my RA axis. I tried the following 2 methods and my output axes were the same (ticks: 5h 42m 15s, 00, 41m 45s, ...)

```
filename = get_pkg_data_filename('flame.fits')
hdu = fits.open(filename)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
plt.xlabel('RA')
plt.ylabel('Dec')
plt.show()
```

METHOD 2:

```
flame = fits.getdata('flame.fits')
hdr   = fits.getheader('flame.fits')
wcs   = WCS(hdr) 

ax = plt.subplot(projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(flame, origin='lower')
plt.xlabel('RA')
plt.ylabel('Dec')
plt.show()
```

How do I change the X-axis (RA) to degrees?
Thanks!

P.S.:
This

```
ax = fig.gca()
ra = ax.coords[0]
dec = ax.coords[1]
ra.set_format_unit('ra')
dec.set_format_unit('dec')
```

result in **AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'coords'**

Comment: If you know the conversion formula between h:m:s and degrees, you can use [`ax.set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) and [`ax.set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) to explicitly set the x-axis tick mark positions and labels

Comment: Have you tried using [AplPy](https://aplpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fitsfigure/arbitrary_coordinate_systems.html)? It's often quicker and easier than trying to do these kinds of plots manually.